# How Can I put editor tabs headers at right in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tabs

I would like to put editor tabs headers at the right side in eclipse. In that way I could see more opened tabs. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

Click the tab header and drag it to the the right side of the editor. Grey boxes will show you how the two editors get placed to each other.

Comment: sorry I would like to move the headers not the entire tabs

Comment: @bigluis that's not possible.